# How can I get proper ShiftState values and Escape keys with Freepascal using the Keyboard unit

Tags: keyboard, console-application, freepascal

I try to implement a console driven multi-threaded application with FreePascal and steered by the keyboard. I'm using FreePascal version 3.2.2 under Ubuntu 18.04 from a the GUAKE Terminal. The threaded part works well but I got problems with the key codes recognition. None of the Shift and Alt keys is recognized and reported excepting if I use a ESC-S key stroke. The shown CTRL text is genereated by checking the character range of the ASCII-tagged characters.

Usually the function `ShiftStateToString(aEvent, TRUE|FALSE))` should give text hints like ALT, CTRL and SHIFT but in my test it is always empty.

https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/keyboard/getkeyeventshiftstate.html

The Escape key works only in addition with a following keystroke.

Is there a possibility to configure and run the matter in a correct way.

## Example Output

```
./TestEscape 
Press F10 to stop

# SHIFT-S pressed 
KEV.CODE:  1F53 DEC: 8019
KEV.STATE: 00 DEC: 0
STR.STATE: 
KEV.FLAGS: 00 BIN: 00000000
KEV.DEBUG: ASCII-S

# ALT-S Pressed
KEV.CODE:  1F00 DEC: 7936
KEV.STATE: 00 DEC: 0
STR.STATE: 
KEV.FLAGS: 03 BIN: 00000011
KEV.DEBUG: PHYS-7936

# ESC-S pressed
KEV.CODE:  1F00 DEC: 7936
KEV.STATE: 08 DEC: 8
STR.STATE: ALT
KEV.FLAGS: 03 BIN: 00000011
KEV.DEBUG: ALT-PHYS-7936

# Pressed the Stop Key F10
KEV.CODE:  FF0A DEC: 65290
KEV.STATE: 00 DEC: 0
STR.STATE: 
KEV.FLAGS: 02 BIN: 00000010
KEV.DEBUG: FUNC-F10

KEV.FINISH: BY.TERM.KEY
.READY
```

## Example Code

```pascal
program TestEscape;

{$MODE DELPHI}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}

uses SysUtils, Keyboard;

type

  TUInt32 = Cardinal;
  TUInt16 = Word;
  TUInt8  = Byte;
  TBool   = Boolean;
  TChar   = Char;
  TString = String;

{ Create a compressed debug string using the functionalty of
  following the example:
  https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/keyboard/getkeyevent.html }
Function EventAsString(aKeyEvent : TKeyEvent) : TString;
var
   lChr: TChar;
begin
  { Check if ther is a Shft Stat String is available }
  Result :=ShiftStateToString(aKeyEvent,False);

  { Add a sepearator if something was found }
  if Result <> '' then Result += '-';

  Case GetKeyEventFlags(aKeyEvent) of
    kbASCII   : begin
       lChr := GetKeyEventChar(aKeyEvent);
       { Bring in an artificial control string because the flag
         is not provided }
       if (Ord(lChr) > 0) and (Ord(lChr) < 32)  then begin
         Result += 'CTRL-'+Chr(65+Ord(lChr))
       end else begin
         Result += 'ASCII-' + lChr;
       end;
    end;

    kbUniCode : Result += 'UTF8-'+IntToStr(GetKeyEventUniCode(aKeyEvent));
    kbFnKey   : Result += 'FUNC-'+FunctionKeyName(GetKeyEventCode(aKeyEvent));
    kbPhys    : Result += 'PHYS-'+IntToStr(aKeyEvent and $ffff);
  end;
end;

{ Handle the key event, dive some status messages and check if
  the termiantion key was pressed }
function HandleEvent(AEvent: TKeyEvent; ATermKey: TUInt16): TBool;
var
    LCode:   TUInt16;
    LSst:    TUInt8;
    LFlg:    TUInt8;
begin
    Result := TRUE;
    { Dismantle the parts of the event records }
    LCode := TkeyRecord(AEvent).KeyCode;
    LFlg  := TkeyRecord(AEvent).Flags;
    LSst  := TkeyRecord(AEvent).ShiftState;
    Writeln('KEV.CODE:  ', HexStr(LCode, 4), ' DEC: ', LCode);
    Writeln('KEV.STATE: ', HexStr(LSst,  2), ' DEC: ', LSst);
    Writeln('STR.STATE: ', ShiftStateToString(AEvent, TRUE));
    Writeln('KEV.FLAGS: ', HexStr(LFlg,  2), ' BIN: ', BinStr(LFlg, 8));
    Writeln('KEV.DEBUG: ', EventAsString(AEvent));
    Writeln;
    { Check if the program can be terminated }
    if LCode = ATermKey then begin
       writeln('KEV.FINISH: BY.TERM.KEY');
       Result:= FALSE;
    end;
end;

var
   GRawEvt:  TKeyEvent;
   GTrsEvt:  TKeyEvent;
   GRun:     TBool;
   GIdle:    TUInt32;
   GTermKey: TUInt16 = kbdF10;

{ === MAIN =============================================================== }
begin
  GRun  := TRUE; { Loop flag }
  GIdle := 1;

  InitKeyboard;

  Writeln('Press F10 to stop');
  while GRun do begin
     { Sleep for 1 ms between the keybord checks }
     Sleep(GIdle);

     if KeyPressed then begin
        GRawEvt := GetKeyEvent; { Get the raw key event }
        GTrsEvt := TranslateKeyEvent(GRawEvt); { translate the matter }
         { Show messeages and check the termination key }
        GRun    := HandleEvent(GTrsEvt, GTermKey );
     end;

  end;

  DoneKeyboard;
  Writeln('.READY');
end.
```